# Controlling Excel Window size and Shape size

Tags: excel, vba

I have a couple of bits of code to manipulate the window size of the excel window to make the window match to the size of the shape (named background)

My problem is, is that the height and width of the shape and the window, don't match.

Is there something that I am missing? Shouldn't pixels equate to pixels?

Workbook activate module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
' Hide Ribbon and Controls
Dim Background As Shape

Set Background = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes("Background")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""RIBBON"", FALSE)"
    .DisplayFormulaBar = False
    .WindowState = xlNormal
    .Height = Background.Height
    .Width = Background.Width
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
End With
With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayHeadings = False
    .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    .DisplayHeadings = False
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
    .ScrollColumn = 1
    .ScrollRow = 1
End With
End Sub
```

Workbook Deactivate module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
' Show all Controls and Ribbon
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""RIBBON"", TRUE)"
    .DisplayFormulaBar = True
End With
With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayHeadings = True
    .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    .DisplayHeadings = True
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
End With
End Sub
```

Sheet Change module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim Background As Shape

Set Background = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set Background = Sh.Shapes("Background")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Background Is Nothing Then
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Height = Background.Height
        .Width = Background.Width
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .ScrollColumn = 1
        .ScrollRow = 1
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Could someone help as to why these don't match?

Many Thanks

Edit added screenshot: Background is black square (Had to remove actual image for confidentiality purposes). White around the edge is excel background

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: can you try something? What happens if you change the size of your background shape to make it smaller? does the window size down proportionately, or does the excel window stay the same size? I seem to remember having to deal with this on a previous project, but want to see what this does for you.

Comment: It sizes down proportionally. It seems like Excel adds in a border

Comment: That confirms it. As I recall Excel does some black magic and sizes the window separately. But, since it is proportional, you can play around with some algebra to get the window size closer to the image size. Or, be lazy like me, and use a color for the white space you see in your screen show that is similar to your image so the appearance is less shocking to the eye.

Comment: Haha ok - I had wondered about playing around with a formula. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: I'm having this same issue too - excel is reporting a width and height much smaller than it actually is. Did you ever come up with a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know what you think :

After the line:

```
Set Background = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes("Background")
```

add:

```
Background.Left = 0
Background.Top = 0
```

Comment: The window still comes back as larger. I'm wondering is there any protocol for how Excel treats images. Could it be compressed in view but seen as larger by the system?

Comment: Could you add a print screen ?

Comment: I've added the print screen, however I've had to remove the majority of it for confidentiality. The Black square is the same size as the 'Background' Image. The white is the excess space that it seems to want to add in. Also I ran a script to get the sizes of each as seen by the system: `Window Height: 548.25; Background Height: 548.4374; Window Width: 770.25; Background Width: 770.6249`

Comment: Is the shape an external picture ?

Comment: The measurements you wrote seem very close: 548.25 :: 548.4374,  770.25 :: 770.6249 ,  however in the print screen there seem to be a lot more white space.      Could you try to change  ScreenUpdating = False  (Workbook_Activate) to  ScreenUpdating = True     and let me know if there is a change ?

Comment: They are that's what is confusing me. As I said to guitarthrower above, It seems as if Excel is adding a border around the image. I don't think it is a screenupdating issue, and that is handled elsewhere through out the workbook. I tried with it anyway, and it has returned the same

Comment: What happens when you remove the pic and run Application.Height = 548.25 and Application.Width = 770.25  ? Does the window scale down ?

Comment: If it does not scale down, then I guess it is not the shape\pic that causes  the problem. It may sound stupid, however did you try a computer restart ?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the first time I've written this piece of code. I just walked away last time. What I've done is put in a formula of `.height = background.height - 0.13 * background.height` and `.width = background.width - 0.17 * background.width` It lines up with the picture. It's not a correct formula by any means but works with the image at that size. I'll need to do some more work to figure out what the actual ratio is.

Comment: Ok, sorry I could not help you more.

Comment: @Tom to help others who may come across this same issue, you should write up an answer with what you did to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because you set the window size before you remove scrollbars and workbooktabs etc. The empty space you see is probably the space these scrollbars ... took.