# Viewing the lower right from a selected Range in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If you select a "large" range via VBA (e.g. `range.Select`) which is bigger then the screen size and bring the window/worksheet to the front (e.g. `workbook.Activate`) you will see the top left part of the selected range and whatever else fits on the screen.

Is it possible to show "the opposite" side, the lower right + whatever fits on the screen?

I thought about using something like

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = tmpLastRowNr
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = tmpLastColumnNr
```

But then I will need some kind of solution to determine how much of the table to the upper left of it and set this as an offset...  I found a way to set/check the windowsize with `Application.Height` etc. but I actually need the size of the "table area". Did I miss a command or is this just not possible to do it "directly" (without calculating the visible area "manually" similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946194/controlling-excel-window-size-and-shape-size))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testLastVisColRow()
  Dim LastVisCol As Long, lastVisRow As Long, selLastRow As Long, selLastCol As Long
  Range("A2:Z32").Select 'use here any range...
    lastVisRow = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows.count).Row
    LastVisCol = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Columns(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Columns.count).Column

    selLastRow = Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.count).Row
    selLastCol = Selection.Columns(Selection.Columns.count).Column

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=selLastRow - lastVisRow + 1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=selLastCol - LastVisCol + 1

    If selLastRow > lastVisRow Or selLastCol > LastVisCol Then
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=selLastRow - lastVisRow + 1
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=selLastCol - LastVisCol + 1
        cells(selLastRow, selLastCol).Activate 'in order to perfectly simulate the reverse of the normal behavior :)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: VisibleRange, seems this is what I was looking for...  I give it a try right away! Thanks!

Comment: @Albin: Glad I could help! But didn't my above code answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. In my test the range is sized 5 rows and around 100 columns (different sizes but the biggest around 1/10 of the screen width). Applying your procedure creates a "split screen" with the 100th column roughly being in the middle of the screen. But don't worry I can take it from here... If not I'll let you know.

Comment: And I didn't know about "ActiveWindow.SmallScroll" either... thats helpfull as well.

Comment: I got it to work just scrolling all the way to the right and then via a loop in 1 column increments. Not the most elegant way, it might have problems if you have hidden columns, but it works in my specific case since there is a max. of 30 columns on the screen at any time.